# remove netns: unlinkat device or resource busy

Tags: kubernetes

Today I found the kubernetes v1.26 cluster contains some warning message like this:

```
error determining status: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox ip: check network namespace closed: remove netns: unlinkat /var/run/netns/cni-99c83d58-2dda-f190-cc48-dcf8d4e2c585: device or resource busy
```

this waring count up to 829015. why did this happen? is it possible to fixed this waring? this is the event detail info:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Event
metadata:
  name: dolphin-post-service-79df79d7f7-zww7x.178bbf67fb75133c
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
  uid: 6a1f130a-58f0-461f-b845-dae9dd1a78d7
  resourceVersion: '154732602'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-10-26T11:38:50Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubelet
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-10-26T11:48:50Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:count: {}
        f:firstTimestamp: {}
        f:involvedObject: {}
        f:lastTimestamp: {}
        f:message: {}
        f:reason: {}
        f:reportingComponent: {}
        f:reportingInstance: {}
        f:source:
          f:component: {}
          f:host: {}
        f:type: {}
  selfLink: >-
    /api/v1/namespaces/reddwarf-pro/events/dolphin-post-service-79df79d7f7-zww7x.178bbf67fb75133c
involvedObject:
  kind: Pod
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
  name: dolphin-post-service-79df79d7f7-zww7x
  uid: 0b9ae753-aee9-404a-9998-2381ca82b267
  apiVersion: v1
  resourceVersion: '150976318'
reason: FailedSync
message: >-
  error determining status: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get
  sandbox ip: check network namespace closed: remove netns: unlinkat
  /var/run/netns/cni-99c83d58-2dda-f190-cc48-dcf8d4e2c585: device or resource
  busy
source:
  component: kubelet
  host: k8smasterone
firstTimestamp: '2023-10-07T06:28:57Z'
lastTimestamp: '2023-10-26T11:48:50Z'
count: 829165
type: Warning
eventTime: null
reportingComponent: kubelet
reportingInstance: k8smasterone
```